# How to install Ubuntu image form boot able Usb on other machine?

Tags: live-usb, iso, cd-image

I created iso image of my Ubuntu 12.04 with Remastersys. now I want to install this iso image on other PC. I used yumi to make my usb bootable but this iso doesn't install on other PC. is there any other method for installing iso image on different machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use builtin prog called: startup disk creator, to create bootable usb from iso.

just open the dash and type "startup disk creator"

Answer (score 0):

Use UnetBootIn. [Download here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/). Usage [Instructions here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Its easy, simple and effective.